# Converting Function with Two Successive "Tail" Recursive Calls to Iterative Function

Tags: loops, recursion, stack, iteration

I've seen plenty of examples on how to convert a function with a single recursive call at the very end into an iterative version; however, what about when there are two recursive calls right at the end?

Here's an example of what I mean, in Python:

```
def doit(x, y, L):
  if x < y:
    x += 1
  else:
    x -= 1
    y -= 1
  if y > 0:
    L.append(x)
    doit(x, y, L)
    doit(x - 1, y - 1, L)

#usage
L = []
doit(3, 5, L)
print(L)
```

Notice that the two recursive calls are right at the very end.  Irrespective of whatever I'm doing in the code before those two recursive calls, is there a general method to convert something like this to an iterative version?  Remember, what I provided above was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no *general* and *simple* method for this as there is for tail recursive case. It's true even if you have 1 recursive call at the end but the function isn't tail recursive (e.g `return 5+foo(x)`). You'll have to explicitly maintain a stack, and then it will work even for cases with more than two recursive calls at the end.

To see why, note that every single variable in a tail-recursive function (meaning parameters and local variables) can have at most one possible value at any given moment. So you never need to maintain more than one version of them in the RAM. Because the moment next recursive call is made, a good compiler will destroy their current version and allocate new version at the same place they are currently in. So it's basically just modifying a variable than allocating new ones.

So for normal recursive functions without that "max 1 version" guarantee, declare a stack before main loop. Every element in it will be a tuple of all parameters. Inside the loop, get stack's last element (& remove it from stack). Then simply copy/paste you function body inside the loop. However, except making next recursive call, create an element containing that call's all parameter values and push it on stack. Your code modified :

```
A = [] #your initial 'L'
stack = [(2,4,A)] #push values of initial call
while stack:
    x,y,L = stack.pop()
    print(x,y)
    if x < y:
        x += 1
    else:
        x -= 1
        y -= 1
    if y > 0:
        L.append(x)
        stack.append((x, y, L))
        stack.append((x - 1, y - 1, L))
```

However, his will work only when order of recursive call doesn't matter, like for dfs. Otherwise, I have an idea for "internal stack" but this answer is already getting too long.

Comment: You need to switch the order of your stack.append() statements.

Comment: That'll work only for this specific example, that's not a general solution